# Dynamic SQL Queries with Python and mySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python

I have multiple tables that are updated after a value is changed in a grid. These tables don't always have the same keys or columns so I cannot explicitly name the columns or formats. The only thing that is ever the same, is the column where the keys reside. I know the way I am currently doing this is not correct and leaves me open to injection attacks.

I also ran into an issue where some of the values contain keys that throw an error in the SQL statement. For example, updating `WHERE email = t'est@email.com`.

I am not really sure of the proper way to write these statements. I did some research and see multiple methods for different purposes but am not sure which is proper. I am looking to do this as dynamically as possible. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

To connect:

```
import mysql.connector as sql
import MySQLdb

#Connect
self.db_name = 'database'
        self.server = 'server'
        self.user_id = 'user'
        self.pw = 'password'

        try:
            self.db_con = MySQLdb.connect(user=self.user_id,password=self.pw,database=self.db_name,
                                    host=self.server,charset='utf8',autocommit=True)
            self.cursor = self.db_con.cursor()
        except:
            print("Error connecting")
```

SQL Statements:

```
key_id =  str("'") + self.GetCellValue(event.GetRow(),1) +  str("'")    
        target_col = self.GetColLabelValue(event.GetCol())
        key_col = self.GetColLabelValue(1)                                     
        nVal = str("'") + self.GetCellValue(event.GetRow(),event.GetCol()) +  str("'")

#SQL STATEMENTS
        sql_update = "UPDATE " + tbl + " SET " +  target_col + " = " + nVal + " WHERE " + key_col  +  " = " + key_id + ""
        

#INSERT
        sql_update = ("INSERT INTO " + str(self.tbl) + "(" + self.key_col + ")" + "VALUES (" + str("'") + str(val) + str("'") + ")")

#DELETE
        sql_update = "DELETE FROM " + tbl + " WHERE " + self.key_col + " = " + self.key_id + ""

#SELECT
        sql_query = "SELECT * FROM " + self.tbl 

#Excecute
        try:
            self.cursor.execute(sql_update)
            
            
        except:
            print('Error')
            self.db_con.rollback()
```

Comment: From where do you get the values for the query, do you have any front-end for that?

Comment: The values database and server are explicit in my code. User and password is determined when the user logs in. Tbl is determined by selections in a combobox. Target_col, key_col, key_id, and nVal are pulled from the wxgrid tabl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Databases have different notations for "quoting" [*identifiers*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html) (table and column names etc) and *values* (data).

MySQL uses *backticks* to quote identifiers.  For values, it's best to use the parameter substitution mechanism provided by the connector package: it's more likely to handle tricky cases like embedded quotes correctly, and will reduce the risk of SQL injection.

Here's an example for inserts; the same techniques can be used for the other types of query.

```py
key_id =  str("'") + self.GetCellValue(event.GetRow(),1) +  str("'")    
target_col = self.GetColLabelValue(event.GetCol())
key_col = self.GetColLabelValue(1)                                     
nVal = str("'") + self.GetCellValue(event.GetRow(),event.GetCol()) +  str("'")
        

#INSERT (using f-strings for brevity)
sql_update = (f"INSERT INTO `{self.tbl}` (`{self.key_col}`) VALUES (%s)")

# Pass the statement and values to cursor.execute.  
# The values are assumed to be a sequence, so a single value should be 
# placed in a tuple or list.
self.cursor.execute(sql_update, (nVal,))
```

If you have more than one column / value pair you could do something like this:

```py
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C']
vals = ['a', 'b', 'c']

col_names = ','.join([f'`{c}`' for c in cols])
values_placeholder = ','.join(['%s'] * len(cols))

sql_update = (f"INSERT INTO `{self.tbl}` (col_names) VALUES ({values_placeholder})")
self.cursor.execute(sql_update, vals)
```

Values are not only data for insertion, but also data that we are using for comparison, for example in `WHERE` clauses.  So an update statement with a filter might be created like this:

```py
sql_update = (f"UPDATE `{tbl}` SET (`{target_col}`) = (%s) WHERE (`{key_col}`) = %s")
self.cursor.execute(sql_update, (nVal, key_id))
```

However sometimes the target of a `SET` or `WHERE` clause may be a column, for example we want to do an update based on other values in the row.  For example, this statement will set `target_col` to the value of `other_col` for all rows where `key_col` is equal to `other_key_col`:

```py
sql_update = (f"UPDATE `{tbl}` SET (`{target_col}`) = `{other_col}` WHERE (`{key_col}`) = `{other_key_col}`")
self.cursor.execute(sql_update)
```

Comment: This works great! However, it should be ```self.cursor.execute```

Comment: Could you explain this method a bit more or point me to some reading material? I ws able to successfully make Insert and Delete Statements. However, I cannot make the Update statement work like this, and I don't understand why. sql_update = (f"UPDATE `{tbl}` SET (`{target_col}`) = (%s) WHERE (`{key_col}`) = `{key_id}`"). self.cursor.execute(sql_update, (nVal,))