# PyMySQL escaping args does not work for database names

Tags: python-3.x, pymysql

To prevent SQL injections I do not use f-Strings or the `format()` for queries with dynamic content. This works fine for alle CRUD operations on tables. But when I try to create a test database with it, it does not work. My code is simple:

```py
def test_create_and_load_dump(connection):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("CREATE OR REPLACE DATABASE %s", ("foo",))
```

`connection` is just the normal `pymysql.Connection`.
This code raises the following error:

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''foo'' at line 1")
```

The raw query after the execution of `mogrify()` from `PyMySQL` is

```sql
'CREATE OR REPLACE DATABASE \'foo\''
```

So it escapes the `'` characters which causes the error above.
Is this a bug in the `PyMySQL` library or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic SQL Queries with Python and mySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68333576/dynamic-sql-queries-with-python-and-mysql)

Comment: Not really. He says "using f-strings for brevity" and inserts the table name via f-string in the query. But the linked answer does not explain why my approach does not work and how to avoid f-strings here.

Comment: Your approach does not work because the database name is an _identifier_, not a _value_.  `cursor.execute` only substitutes values, you need to handle identifiers yourself, usually by using a string formatting technique to insert them into the SQL statement.

Comment: Okay, but how can I minimize the risk of SQL injections while doing that? It sounds very risky to me.

Comment: If you have to accept identifiers from untrusted sources then you could try a few techniques: validation (for example, no spaces); maintain a mapping of user-exposed names to real identifiers, maintain an allow-list of permitted names.  And always quote identifiers with backticks.