# Use of variable in SQL query

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I want to use a variable in the Select Query but it give me a fail. Someone can guide me how to insert this variable in my SQL query ?

---

```
project = test

# Our SQL Query
Query_1 = """
SELECT * FROM project.dataplex_dq.dq-results`
"""
# labelling our query job
query_job_1 = client.query(Query_1)

# results as a dataframe
Table = query_job_1.result().to_dataframe()
```

Comment: What variable?  How does it fail?

Comment: Basically If I use for instance SELECT * FROM test.dataplex_dq.dq-results` it will work it will display me information. But in the future it is possible the location will become test2.dataplex_dq.dq-results` So I want to make my code generic and not to have to change it everytime. I want to store this info in a variable and use it in the query then

Comment: MYSQL does not do variable substitution for objects (eg tables, columns etc) for that you need dynamic sql.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic SQL Queries with Python and mySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68333576/dynamic-sql-queries-with-python-and-mysql)